# react native : What is the way to populate the EmergencyRolePicker picker in data with a map function rather than hardcoded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

What is the way to populate the EmergencyRolePicker picker in data with a map function rather than hardcoded?
In my example I am trying to populate the picker but I want to do it with a map loop so I can select something from the picker.
The picker comes from the react-native-paper library.
I would be happy for some help with this issue.

**this is my code:**

```
import { List } from 'react-native-paper';


export const ActionsScreen = () => {
  const [roleList, setRoleList] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        // State table
        const emcStateList: EmergencyStateType[] = await EmergencyStateTable.getEmergencyStateList();
        console.log('emcStateList:', emcStateList.length);
        let items = [];
        emcStateList.forEach(function (item, i) {
          items.push({ label: item.EmergencyName, value: item.EmergencyCode, key: i });
        })
        setStateList(items);
        // Role table
        const emcRoleList: EmergencyRoleType[] = await EmergencyRoleTable.getEmergencyRoleList();
        console.log('emcRoleList:', emcRoleList.length);
        items = [];
        emcRoleList.forEach(function (item, i) {
          items.push({ label: item.RoleName, value: item.RoleCode, key: i });
        })
        setRoleList(items);
        //
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('A problem getting emergency list from db:', error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);


  const EmergencyRolePicker = () => {
    return (
      <List.Accordion title={roleList[0].label} id="0">
        <List.Item title={roleList[1].label} />
        <List.Item title={roleList[2].label} />       
      </List.Accordion>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.text}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>{MenuStrings.EmergencyRole}</Text>
            <View style={styles.pickerView}>
              <EmergencyRolePicker />
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.BottomViewArea}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 60 }}
          onPress={() => {
          }}>
          <Ionicons
            name="send-sharp"
            size={30}
            color="white"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

**this is the data:**

```
[
   {
      "key":0,
      "label":"red",
      "value":1
   },
   {
      "key":1,
      "label":"green",
      "value":2
   },
   {
      "key":2,
      "label":"yellow",
      "value":3
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the for loop, using the map as already mentioned by you would look like this:

```
let items = emcStateList.map((item, i) => ({
      label: item.EmergencyName,
      value: item.EmergencyCode,
      key: i
    })
 setStateList(items);
```

As a sidenote, I would not use the index as a key, if the codes are unique, use those.

Also calling the endpoints one after another causes a waterwall. Instead try this:

```
const emcStateListPromise: Promise<EmergencyStateType[]> = EmergencyStateTable.getEmergencyStateList();
const emcRoleListPromise: Promise<EmergencyRoleType[]> = EmergencyRoleTable.getEmergencyRoleList();
const emcStateList = await emcStateListPromise
const emcRoleList = await emcRoleListPromise
```

Update:

```
useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  try {
    // State table
    const emcStateList: EmergencyStateType[] = await EmergencyStateTable.getEmergencyStateList();
 let items = emcStateList.map((item, i) => ({
      label: item.EmergencyName,
      value: item.EmergencyCode,
      key: i
    }))
 setStateList(items);
    // Role table
    const emcRoleList: EmergencyRoleType[] = await EmergencyRoleTable.getEmergencyRoleList();
    console.log('emcRoleList:', emcRoleList.length);
    items = emcRoleList.map((item, i) => ({
      label: item.RoleName, value: item.RoleCode, key: i 
    }))
    setRoleList(items);
    //
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('A problem getting emergency list from db:', error);
  }
})();
```

}, []);

Comment: can you show me please your example into my code ?

Comment: 1. I just want you to implement your example within my code listed above.
2. After selecting something from the picker then it will display coz at the moment nothing can be selected from the picker.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with what I want to achieve.
I want you to show me how you implement the map within my code.
2. I want you to show me how to select an item from the picker because at the moment it is not possible to select at all.